# IE11, button has no more hover effect after background color change

Tags: javascript, css, button, hover

I have some buttons that represents "tools". The buttons are styled like this:

```
.button {
    background-color: #DDDDDD;
    border: none;
    color: black;
    border-radius: 8px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.button:hover {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
```

When you click on one of them I change the background color to highlight the tool you're using and I reset the background of the tools not in use, for example:

```
document.getElementById("buttonPencil").style.backgroundColor = "red";
document.getElementById("buttonEraser").style.backgroundColor = "#DDDDDD";
document.getElementById("buttonBucket").style.backgroundColor = "#DDDDDD";
```

The issue is that after this style change the hover effect is not working properly anymore on those buttons (in fact only the text color inside the buttons changes on hover).
Can someone explain me how to fix this and why it's happening?

Comment: inline style has highest specificity in CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As inline style are the HIGHEST PRIORITY in css. Your style color was ignored in CSS.

By such, you need to add `!important` to the CSS to make sure it override any other style.

```js
document.getElementById("buttonPencil").style.backgroundColor = "red";
document.getElementById("buttonEraser").style.backgroundColor = "#DDDDDD";
document.getElementById("buttonBucket").style.backgroundColor = "#DDDDDD";
```

```css
.button {
    background-color: #DDDDDD;
    border: none;
    color: black;
    border-radius: 8px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.button:hover {
    background-color: #4CAF50 !important;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<button id="buttonPencil" class="button">Pencil</button>
<button id="buttonEraser" class="button">Eraser</button>
<button id="buttonBucket" class="button">Bucket</button>
```

By the way, why you need to change the color from JS instead of CSS. 
By changing in CSS, you won't need to add `!important`

E.g

```css
.button {
    background-color: #DDDDDD;
    border: none;
    color: black;
    border-radius: 8px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.button:hover {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

.buttonPencil { background-color: red; }
.buttonEraser, .buttonBucket { background-color: #DDDDDD; }
```

```html
<button class="button buttonPencil">Pencil</button>
<button class="button buttonEraser">Eraser</button>
<button class="button buttonBucket">Bucket</button>
```

Comment: please vote it up or mark as answer if it was helpful.. Also, glad to hear it

Comment: I'm trying, but it tells me to wait... there's a 5 minutes freeze.

Comment: Or better yet, use classes and do not use important!

Comment: If the user presses on the pencil tool, the pencil tool will have a red background while the other tools will have the default background. Then if he selects the eraser tool, the eraser tool will have the red background and the other tools will have the default background and so on... I guess the CSS above will just set the red background for the pencil and that's it.

Comment: you need to use css to add classes when it clicked and remove it when other was clicked. It almost like toggle button

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the inline style applied from javascript (which is already a bad practice) taking over.

"Fixing" it with !important is an **awful bad** practice.

You should use a modifier to apply the highlight, so it can be easily toggled with .classList.add/remove/toggle("active") and it won't interfere with the :hover state at all.

Something like

```js
/*selects all buttons inside .buttons div*/
var el = document.querySelectorAll('.buttons button');
for (let i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
/*adds on click event to each of them*/
  el[i].onclick = function() {
    var c = 0;
    while (c < el.length) {
    /*removes the active class from all*/
      el[c++].classList.remove ('active');
    }
    /*ads the class to the one clicked*/
    el[i].classList.add('active');
  };
}
```

```css
.button {
        background-color: #DDDDDD;
        border: none;
        color: black;
        border-radius: 8px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 12px;
        padding: 8px 16px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .button:hover {
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        color: white;
    }
    
    .active{
      background:red;
    }
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <button id="buttonPencil" class="button">Pencil</button>
  <button id="buttonEraser" class="button">Eraser</button>
  <button id="buttonBucket" class="button">Bucket</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems an interesting solution. Thanks.

Comment: Apparently classList.remove and classList.add won't work on IE11. IE11 is the only browser where I need to use this tool.

Comment: Seems a lot of code to add for that simple color change... why the use of !important it's so bad? Consider that the tool I'm building will be used only by 60 PCs that run the same OS and IE version. It's not going to be "online".